# Are the following sets regular?

Tags: regex, math, regular-language

I'm currently studying compilers and am having some issues with understanding regular sets. For example, lets say I had a set of binary strings, (0, 1). Would all integers that are even and positive be considered part of a regular set? Lets say I have that same set, but instead of being even, they are divisible by 5, would it still be a regular set?

I've been looking at [this helpful guide I found online](http://www.cs.uky.edu/~lewis/texts/theory/automata/reg-sets.pdf), but I'm still confused about what can be defined as a regular set.

Comment: I know how to write regexes but I've no idea what you're talking about. You maybe should take a look at [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com) and ask it there.

Comment: Yes it is a regular, language How?  If you divide a number with `5` remained can be either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (it like you need five stats in DFA) Appending a bit to a number always moves to one of possible 5 stages only (no other possible move). So an any instance of time you required only bounded information to memorized in order to process language's string Hence Yes it is a Regular Language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would all integers that are even and positive be considered part of a regular set?

Yep! You can generate them with this regular expression:

> 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | (0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)+(0|2|4|6|8)
>
> Lets say I have that same set, but instead of being even, they are divisible by 5, would it still be a regular set?

Yep!  Here's the regex:

> 5 | (0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)+(0|5)

More generally, to determine whether a set is a regular set, you should try to find a finite automaton that accepts precisely the strings in the language or a regular expression for that set. If you can do that, the language is regular. If not, it's not regular.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why didn't you use character classes ? `[02468]|[0-9]+[02468]` which could be simplified to `[0-9]*[02468]`. `[05]|[0-9]+[05]` -> `[0-9]*[05]`. On a side note, don't forget that 0 is divisible by 2 and 5 :)

Comment: @Hamza- Since the question was about mathematical regular expressions rather than software regular expressions, I didn't want to use syntax specific to tools. (Check the OP's link). Also, the question specifically talks about *positive* multiples of 2 and 5, so I deliberately left out 0.